# what are the differences between "I play football for 1 hour per day" and "I play football for 1 hour every day"

Tags: difference

In the dictionary

> [per](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/per?q=per): used to express the cost or amount of something for each person,
>   number used, distance travelled, etc.
>
> Rooms cost £50 per person, per night.
>
> 60 miles per hour
>
> This country has a higher crime rate per 100 000 of the population
>   than most other European countries.

what are the differences between "**I play football for 1 hour per day**" and "**I play football for 1 hour every day**"?

**Are they the same?**

Answer (score 2):

They are almost the same, and in most cases they are interchangeable.

The second version with "every day" does explicitly say that you play every day, so that could make some small difference depending on context. If there would be a reason to assume that you only play certain days, using "per day" doesn't put quite as much emphasis on that.

For example, compare:

> On Monday and Wednesday afternoons, I usually play basketball for a couple hours. I also play football for about one hour per day.
>
> On Monday and Wednesday afternoons, I usually play basketball for a couple hours. I also play football for about one hour every day.

The first one here is somewhat ambiguous about whether football is just on Mondays and Wednesdays or if it is really every day of the week. The second one is pretty clear that it is every day.

An alternative that more closely matches *per day* would be *each day*.